# Python - escaped 4 digit escaped unicode characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I downloaded the source code of a website. Through downloading the source code, and converting it into a string, many of the characters (like single quotes ('), double quotes ("), angled brackets (<, >), and forward slashes (/)) are now double escaped.

Example:

```
s = '\\u2018this \\/ that\\u2019'
```

The text represented in the website, and how i want it represented when printed out is:

`this / that`

My first instinct was to use regex to find all instances of 2 backslashes, and replace it with a single backslash, then use `str.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` to convert the 4 digit escaped Unicode characters into their actual characters:

```
import re
sample = '\\u2018this \\/ that\\u2019'
pattern = r'(\\)\\\1'
double_escapes_removed = re.sub(pattern, '', text)
final_text = text.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

`print(final_text)` should return `this / that`, but the returned string appears to be completely unaltered: `\u2018this \/ that\u2019`.

I tested the pattern individually with `re.findall(pattern, text)`, and it successfully found the 3 instances of double backslashes. Beyond that, I have no idea what is going wrong

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a bit difficult. A big part of the issue is that although '\u2018' is 6 characters, '\u2018' is a representation of a single character, so you can't just replace '\u' with '\u' and have it work.

This gets you most of the way there without having to manually iterate over escapes with regex:

```
>>> s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
<<< '‘this \\/ that’'
```

Python 3 does output a warning about `'\/'` being an invalid unicode escape sequence, so you'd probably want to take care of those first.

Comment: Thank you for saving my time